# PHP parse XML feed with non consistent objects

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xpath

I need to process an external XML feed into my Mysql DB. The XML feed contains real estate objects. The problem is that the number of fields in a node are not consistent. Some nodes (real estate objects) have extra field or missing some fields.

Here is a part of 2 real estate objects:

```
<Object>
<ObjectCode>CM10272</ObjectCode>
<ObjectDetails>
<Adres>
<Nederlands>
<Straatnaam>Dokter van Nieveltweg</Straatnaam>
<Huisnummer>0</Huisnummer>
**<HuisnummerToevoeging>ong</HuisnummerToevoeging>**
<Postcode>1901 GD</Postcode>
<Woonplaats>CASTRICUM</Woonplaats>
<Land>NL</Land>
</Nederlands>
</Adres>
etc


<Object>
<ObjectCode>CM10280</ObjectCode>
<ObjectDetails>
<Adres>
<Nederlands>
<Straatnaam>De Houtwal</Straatnaam>
<Huisnummer>44</Huisnummer>
<Postcode>1852 RP</Postcode>
<Woonplaats>HEILOO</Woonplaats>
<Land>NL</Land>
</Nederlands>
</Adres>
etc
```

As you can see the first node has an extra element called "HuisnummerToevoeging".

I process the xml feed with the use of XPATH:

```
$values = <<<XPATH
(
    ObjectCode
    |ObjectDetails/Adres/Nederlands/Straatnaam
    |ObjectDetails/Adres/Nederlands/Huisnummer
    |ObjectDetails/Adres/Nederlands/HuisnummerToevoeging
    |ObjectDetails/Adres/Nederlands/Postcode
    |ObjectDetails/Adres/Nederlands/Woonplaats

)
XPATH;

$pattern = <<<SQL
INSERT INTO woningen
  (
    ObjectCode, Straat, Huisnr, Huistoe, Postcode, Woonplaats, PrijsVoorvoegsel, Prijs, PrijsCondiditie
  )
  VALUES
  (
    '%s','%s', '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%d', '%s'
  )
SQL;

foreach ($woning as $woning)
{
    $data = $woning->xpath($values);
    $escaped = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data);
    $query = vsprintf($pattern, $escaped);

    //INSERT INTO MYSQL
}
```

How can I skip elements that doesn't not exist in the XML feed? I have to total of 70 fields to process for each real estate object, some only using 10 fields. Also the XML feed can be update with extra fields without notice, so I need to handle this in a smart way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another way to solve the problem.

I created an Array of variables and xpaths to the value:

```
$NeedData = array(  "ObjectCode"=>"ObjectCode",
                    "Straat"=>"ObjectDetails/Adres/Nederlands/Straatnaam",
                    "Huisnr"=>"ObjectDetails/Adres/Nederlands/Huisnummer",
                    "Huistoe"=>"ObjectDetails/Adres/Nederlands/HuisnummerToevoeging",
                    "Postcode"=>"ObjectDetails/Adres/Nederlands/Postcode",
                    "Woonplaats"=>"ObjectDetails/Adres/Nederlands/Woonplaats",
                 etc
```

Then with a small foreach loop I check if a element exist withing the XML object, if not then I set the value to "null"

```
foreach ($XML_woning as $woning){

    foreach($NeedData as $key=>$value){
        $val = $woning->xpath($value);
        if($value!=""){
            if(isset($val[0])){
                $$key = $val[0];
            }else{
                $$key="null";
            }
        }else{
            $$key="null";
        }
    }
```